# Cmake: pkg_check_modules error: Package '...', required by 'virtual:world', not found

Tags: c++, windows, netbeans, cmake

I am trying to build a c++ project with Netbeans in Windows but during the pre-built process an error relating to the CMakeLists I used comes out. Here is the error output:

```
cd 'E:\Yifan\Hiwi-FSD\FluCo1\Sourcecode\branch_HighLevelUmstrukturierung\High-Level\FCU-Interface\build-dev'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/cmake.exe -G Unix Makefiles -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=E:/Yifan/Hiwi-FSD/FluCo1/Sourcecode/branch_HighLevelUmstrukturierung/High-Level/FCU-Interface/nbproject/private/tools/localhost/MinGW_1/gcc.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=E:/Yifan/Hiwi-FSD/FluCo1/Sourcecode/branch_HighLevelUmstrukturierung/High-Level/FCU-Interface/nbproject/private/tools/localhost/MinGW_1/g++.exe -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG=-g3 -gdwarf-2 -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG=-g3 -gdwarf-2 -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON -DPROJECT_SUFFIX=-dev -DPKG_CONFIG_USE_CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=TRUE -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=E:\Yifan\Hiwi-FSD\FluCo1\Libraries\fsd-libs\trunk\build-dev\install ..
-- SVN Revision Number is 
-- FCU-Interface-dev PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR = E:/Yifan/Hiwi-FSD/FluCo1/Sourcecode/branch_HighLevelUmstrukturierung/High-Level/FCU-Interface
-- FCU-Interface-dev Build directory = E:/Yifan/Hiwi-FSD/FluCo1/Sourcecode/branch_HighLevelUmstrukturierung/High-Level/FCU-Interface/build-dev
-- Checking for module 'fsd-io-dev'
--   Package 'fsd-io-dev', required by 'virtual:world', not found
CMake Error at C:/msys64/mingw64/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:561 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/msys64/mingw64/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:783 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  CMakeLists.txt:17 (pkg_check_modules)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "E:/Yifan/Hiwi-FSD/FluCo1/Sourcecode/branch_HighLevelUmstrukturierung/High-Level/FCU-Interface/build-dev/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

PRE-BUILD FAILED (exit value 1, total time: 5s)
```

And the CMakelists file is shown below:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

SET(FSD_LIB_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../../../../Libraries)
include("${FSD_LIB_DIR}/CMakeSuffixBase.cmake")
project("FCU-Interface${PROJECT_SUFFIX}" VERSION 0.1)

SET(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH} ${FSD_LIB_DIR}/fsd-libs/trunk/build${PROJECT_SUFFIX}/install/lib/pkgconfig)
include("${FSD_LIB_DIR}/CMakeBase.cmake")
include(FindPkgConfig)

Subversion_GET_REVISION(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} SVN_REV)
message(STATUS "SVN Revision Number is ${SVN_REV}")
message(STATUS "${PROJECT_NAME} PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR = ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}")
message(STATUS "${PROJECT_NAME} Build directory = ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}")

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(FSD_IO REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET fsd-io${PROJECT_SUFFIX})

set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)

file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCE_FILES "src/*.cpp")
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
    VERSION "${PROJECT_VERSION}+${SVN_REV}"
)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/>
)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../Framework_Seitz>
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
    Threads::Threads
    PkgConfig::FSD_IO)

install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR})
```

The `PROJECT_SUFFIX` is `-dev`. I reckon that the problem is, the file `"fsd-io-dev.pc"` cannot be found. But I already have it under the directory `"E:\Yifan\Hiwi-FSD\FluCo1\Libraries\fsd-libs\trunk\build-dev\install\lib\pkgconfig"`. What should I do to let it be found? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: 1. Netbeans is IDE which can use variant toolchains. 2. Which compiler do you use: msvc or gcc or clang? Looks like it is gcc. 3. If this is msvc then use [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg) to install required package. Do not remember how to handle this for gcc 4. Did you read README.md of project you are building? What project it is?

Comment: @MarekR Hi, thank you very much for your reply. I use gcc as my default compiler. Actually this is a project from my university and there is no README.md file. I follow exactly the instructions from my tutor, but end up with an error that he has never met before.